# Taking a || (or) statement as input?

Tags: java

I have this class with a foo method and the main method where I have a few variables and a print statement.

```
public static boolean foo(int x, boolean b) {
    if (x < 0) {
          return true;
    }
    return !b; 
}
```

Say I print the following:

```
foo (-3, c || !c)
```

I'm having trouble understanding what the || is supposed to do.  I declared boolean c = false in main, but I don't see how it can choose to input c (false) or !c (true).  Also, side-question: the exclamation point in front of a boolean variable will just give the opposite right? i.e. if the input was false, and foo returns !b, it'd return true?

Comment: It doesn't choose. || is a logical operator. true || false evaluates to true, because at least one is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a tautology so to speak, always true.

`c || !c`  means: "c **OR** not c".  One of these is always true.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't see how it can choose to input c (false) or !c (true)

It's not "choosing to input" two different possibilities. It's passing the **value** that is the **result of evaluating** `c || !c`, a single boolean.

Note: `x || !x` will always evaluate to `true`, for any boolean value of `x`.

Comment: I'm going to bed, but perhaps you can expand on evaluation order and side effects, if functions are used.

Answer (score 1):

`c || !c` will always be `true` - you might as well replace the code with

```
foo (-3, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declared `c` as:

```
 boolean c = false;// or true
```

then `c || !c` will always result into `true`.

so you method call `foo (-3, c || !c)` **is nothing but equivalent to  `foo (-3, true)`**

Answer (score 1):

"||" means OR, so any x || !x will always return true, no matter whether you declare x as false or true.